# InjectMock with a non-null mocked object?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm doing InjectMocks and I'm getting this error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: ... is marked non-null but is null" which is due to a Non-Null check that I have. What I want to do is form an InjectMock, but this injectmock is object is constructed using parameters.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

public class Tester {
    @Spy private ClassA clA;
    @InjectMocks 
    private ClassB clB = new clB(clA);


    @BeforeEach
    void setup() throws Exception {
        Mock.when(clA.mymethod(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Non_Null_Stuff);
    }

}
```

I'm sure you can see what I'm trying to do here: create class B using a mocked version of class A, but it doesn't work because it gives me "clA is marked non-null but is null" at the @InjectMocks line. This is because the code for the construction of clB requires a non-null clA.

It seems that I am unable to place the InjectMocks line within the setup function and I cannot place the Mock.when before the InjectMocks, so I'm stuck. Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues here.
The answer depends on what do you want to achieve.

To use Mockito annotations you should add next line above your class (in case if you use jUnit 5):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

And, this dependency to your pom (if you use Maven (you can find analog for Gradle here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.3.3))

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

> @Spy

means that you will be using **real** object (not a mock) and it is mostly used to be able to make verifications on that object (check if certain methods was called appropriate number of times with appropriate arguments, see: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify).

> @Mock

means that you will be using **mocked** object and you should set it's beheviour using Mockito.when()

@Mock is used to exclude logic from being tested and make methods of objects behave in the way you need for particular unit test.

**Hope this snippet of code will help you to understand the difference:**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Test {

    @Spy
    private ClassA classA; // it will be real object

    @Mock
    private ClassB classB; // it will be mock

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassC classC;

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void test() {

        // for mock we should define it's behaviour for the test (here or in @BeforeEach annotated method)
        Mockito.when(classB.mockedMethod()).thenReturn("Some overridden behaviour");

        String result = classC.someMethod();

        assertEquals("ClassA - Some overridden behaviour", result);

        // verity that method on real object wall called
        Mockito.verify(classA, Mockito.only()).realMethod();

        // verity that method on mocked object wall called
        Mockito.verify(classB, Mockito.only()).mockedMethod();

    }
}
```

**ClassA:**

```
public class ClassA {

    public String realMethod() {
        return "ClassA";
    }
}
```

**ClassB:**

```
public class ClassB {

    public String mockedMethod(){
        return "ClassB";  // we will not be using it's real behaviour
    }
}
```

**ClassC:**

```
public class ClassC {

    private ClassA classA;

    private ClassB classB;

    public ClassC(ClassA classA, ClassB classB) {
        this.classA = classA;
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    public String someMethod() {
        return classA.realMethod() + " - " +classB.mockedMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that class C needs to be instantiated with an object from class B that's not null. How would you do it in that case?

Comment: If you would use one of the annotations Spy or Mock (depends on what do you want to achieve) the field with type of class B will already be not null.
Than if you have appropriate constructor in class C, Mockito will automatically put this object to that field if you'd use InjectMocks annotation above that field.
You don't need to create any objects by yourself in this case.

Comment: However it is turning up to be null. Any idea why? It says in the error message that it is null

Comment: Also, just to be clear I did include the @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
but forgot to include it in my example sorry